# Downloading Julia from Anaconda or from julialang.org

Tags: anaconda, julia

I want to download Julia (the last version is 1.0) from Anaconda. However, you can download from https://julialang.org/. My questions are: What are the differences between both ways of installing Julia? Can I install, for example, `DifferentialEquations.jl`or `Symata.jl` without problems if I choose Anaconda? If I choose Anaconda, how good is the package management?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only benefits of Anaconda are, as far I'm aware, that it automatically selects the right binary (i.e., OS), and likely has a slightly easier updating experience (for the language itself). However, it does not seem to support Windows (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/julia), so if you happen to be on that platform, you are out of luck. I would recommend grabbing the binary from the website directly, the installation process is very straightforward.

The management of Julia packages will still happen inside Julia. Julia 1.0 has a very good package manager called `Pkg`. You can read more on installing packages within Julia on https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/stdlib/Pkg/.